# copy file from gcs to s3 in boto3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage, boto3

I am looking to copy files from gcs to my s3 bucket. In boto2, easy as a button.

```
conn = connect_gs(user_id, password)
gs_bucket = conn.get_bucket(gs_bucket_name) 
for obj in bucket:
   s3_key = key.Key(s3_bucket)
   s3_key.key = obj
   s3_key.set_contents_from_filename(obj)
```

However in boto3, I am lost trying to find equivalent code. Any takers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you're doing is a copy:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('bucket-name')
for obj in gcs:
    s3_obj = bucket.Object(gcs.key)
    s3_obj.put(Body=gcs.data)
```

Docs: [`s3.Bucket`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Bucket), [`s3.Bucket.Object`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object), [`s3.Bucket.Object.put`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.put)

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the resource model:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
for obj in gcs:
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket='bucket-name', Key=gcs.key, Body=gcs.body)
```

Docs: [`s3_client.put_object`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object)

Caveat: The `gcs` bits are pseudocode, I am not familiar with their API.

**EDIT:**

So it seems `gcs` supports an old version of the S3 API and with that an old version of the signer. We still have support for that old signer, but you have to opt into it. Note that some regions don't support old signing versions (you can see a list of which S3 regions support which versions [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region)), so if you're trying to copy over to one of those you will need to use a different client.

```
import boto3
from botocore.client import Config

# Create a client with the s3v2 signer
resource = boto3.resource('s3', config=Config(signature_version='s3'))
gcs_bucket = resource.Bucket('phjordon-test-bucket')
s3_bucket = resource.Bucket('phjordon-test-bucket-tokyo')
for obj in gcs_bucket.objects.all():
    s3_bucket.Object(obj.key).copy_from(
        CopySource=obj.bucket_name + "/" + obj.key)
```

Docs: [`s3.Object.copy_from`](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Object.copy_from)

This, of course, will only work assuming `gcs` is still S3 compliant.

Comment: sadly, i think at the moment its not possible... i was getting the gcs key from boto2 i don't think boto3 supports google cloud storage...stupid boto

Comment: Well boto3 is an Amazon product and is not designed to interact with Google services. I believe in this case Google doesn't support the latest authentication schemes, so you will manually need to set to use the old signature version. I'll update my answer with how to do that.